# Smooth transfer of service IP to backup system

Tags: load-balancing, high-availability, keepalived, vrrp

I'm trying to research the best way to find a HA solution plus (little) load balancing for our TCP services.
All solutions I found (e.g. HAProxy, LVS) use a master machine which holds the TCP service IP and when the master crashes a backup system (by keepalived, VRRP) becomes available by using that service IP. That's nice.

But I didn't found a solution for making the backup system the active one by a smooth transfer (without loosing a packet): Sometimes I need to update/change/reboot the current master machine so I want new connections going to the backup system while old/current connections are still handled by the old master until they are done so I am able to reboot the old master.
Is that possible or can't this be done?

And while dreaming: The optimal solution would be a transfer of the current connections (plus the service IP) to the backup machine. Is there a solution for this dream?

Comment: I recommend corosync/pacemaker with stonith too

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after, but if it's "smooth transfer without loosing a packet":

I've never used `keepalived` or `VRRP` implementations, because most (all?) of them lack [STONITH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STONITH), AFAIK.

But: The industry standard for setting up high availability clusters in the open source world, the [corosync / pacemaker stack](http://clusterlabs.org/), provides this.